# Continuity of $f(x,y)$ which is not defined along a path

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity

Consider $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ when $x-y \neq 0$ and $0$ if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

This function is easily shown to be continuous along all paths, but along $x=y$ it is not defined!

So will it said to be continuous at $0,0$ ?

Comment: How have you shown 'easily' that $f$ is continuous along the path, $t \to (t,t)$, say?

Comment: For any other path, we simply have to use first definition, which goes to 0

Comment: Yes of course, but you have said $f$ is continuous *along all paths*. The function $t \mapsto (t,t)$ is a path, but $f$ is not continuous along it. There are many other paths which intersect the ray $x=y$. Do you see the problem?

Comment: @jeea  Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details [HERE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @gimusi sorry I totally forgot about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the continuity at $(0,0)$ it doesn't mind if $f(x,y)$ is not defined for $x=y\neq 0$, indeed we have that trivially

$$\lim_{\substack{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\\\quad \:x\neq y}x^2+y^2=0=f(0,0)$$

therefore by definition $f(x,y)$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: How can you take the limit to $(0,0)$ if the function isn't defined on a neighbourhood of $0$?

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Just take the path $x=t$ and $y=-t$ for example.

Comment: I think you are using a non-standard definition of continuity in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. c.f. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_function#Functions_of_more_than_one_variable)

Comment: @DanielLittlewood Of course we are referring to different definition but I'm not sure that mine is the "non-standard" one. If f(x,y) is not defined for $x=y\neq 0$ it doesn't mind since we are removing those points from the domain. The case seems  similar to this OP https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2889055/what-is-lim-x-to-0-frac-sin-frac-1x-sin-frac-1-x-does-it-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The various definitions given in the answer you link are satisfactory, and establish that the limit equals $0$ (which is true), although I suspect that the OP may have been given a definition which assumes that the domain of $f$ should be a nbhd of $(0,0)$, which would explain the confusion. My serious objection is with your comment: continuity along a path does not imply continuity of the function!

Comment: @DanielLittlewood The limit is derived trivially since, under the condition $x\neq y$, as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ we have that $x^2+y^2 \to 0$ for any path.

Comment: I am still not clear about the part that along $x=y$ function is not defined, so can we even talk about continuity along that path? According to epsilon delta definition limit should exist and f should continuous

Comment: @jeea I'm assuming that by your definition f(x,y) is defined on $$D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}:x\neq y\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$$ In that context is meaningles to consider the continuity for the points $x=y\neq0$ since they are not included in the domain.

Comment: @gimusi i was asking Daniel Littlewood, not you! I agree with you, I was asking  for Daniels point and answer :)

Comment: @jeea Ops sorry...the best thing is ping the person in thst case.