# Calculate the limit $\lim \limits_{x \to 2} \left(\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-2x}\right)$, although $x\neq 2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I should calculate the Limit $\lim \limits_ {x \to 2} \left(\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-2x}\right)$, although I noticed, that $x\neq 2$ must apply. Is the limit undefined? Otherwise, with which steps should I go on to calculate the limit?

Comment: Even there is no "cancellation", the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)$ has nothing to do with the value of the function $f$ at $x=x_0$. For instance $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ is **not** defined at $x=0$ and there is no "cancellation", but we have $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: @user587192 In some sense the cancellation there is also there if we consider that $\frac{\sin x}x=\frac{x+o(x)}{x}=1+o(1)\to 1$. The key point, as younoticed, is that when we take the limit we are considering $x\neq x_0$ (and more in general $x\in [(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)\setminus\{x_0\}]\cap D$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that

$$\frac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-2x}=\frac{\color{red}{(x-2)}(x+4)}{x\color{red}{(x-2)}}=\frac{x+4}{x}$$

and then take the limit.

To clarify why we are allowed to cancel out the $(x-2)$ factor refer to the related

- [Why are we allowed to cancel fractions in limits?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2628911/505767)

Comment: Thank you! I didn't knew I could still simplify like that, because this will obviously fix one "gap".

Comment: @Doesbaddel We can because, by defiition, when we take the limit $x\to 2$ we are considering $x\neq 2$. Refer to the given link for more details on that.

Comment: I looked it up, thank you and have a nice day

Comment: @Doesbaddel Well done, I hope now your doubt is clear. If you are interested refer also to [$\lim_{x \to 0}\;\frac{\sin\left(\frac 1x\right)}{\sin \left(\frac 1 x\right)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889055/505767).

Comment: Thank you man. I voted so fast, that I completely overlooked the other persons answer. Haha

Comment: @Doesbaddel You can change the answer to accept anytime! Just select the which one you prefer and helped you much more. If they are equivalent, in my opinion you should select the first one given, that is the one by Key Flex. Bye

Comment: Yeah, its hard to decide. I would suggest, that one should be allowed to accept more than one answer. I will just leave it like that and consider your tip next time I encounter two equivalently good answers. ;)

Comment: @Doesbaddel The choice is completely up to you! Bye

Answer (score 5):

Given $$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\dfrac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\dfrac{\color{red}{(x-2)}(x+4)}{x\color{red}{(x-2)}}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\dfrac{x+4}{x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}1+\dfrac4x = 3$$

OR

You could also use L'Hopital's rule

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\dfrac{x^2+2x-8}{x^2-2x}=\lim_{x\rightarrow2}\dfrac{2x+2}{2x-2}=\dfrac{2(2)+2}{2(2)-2}=\dfrac{6}{2}=3$$

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I've just seen your post , because I never srolled down.

Comment: @Doesbaddel Why Sorry? Hope my posts helped you.

Comment: I would've labeled your post as accepted otherwise. Unfortunately I was a bit too fast with the first one.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't decide :(( It would be easier to accept more than one answer.

Comment: @Doesbaddel Accept the answer which you feel helped you in solving the above question.

Comment: Actually both of you!