# If there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}\;,\;$ then there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)\;.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis

If there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}\;,\;$ then there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)\;.$

If it is true, prove it.
If it false, give a counterexample.

Could you also do the converse?

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: These are equivalent because both $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ and $x\mapsto x^2$ are continuous for $x\ge0$. If $f(x)\lt0$ then neither implications really make sense.

Comment: Continuous functions commute with taking limits, so you get the same result if you take the limit first and then apply a continuous function, or if you apply a contentious function to the argument of the limit first and take the limit afterwards.

Comment: Are you familiar with the theorem that if $\sqrt$ is continuous then $\lim \sqrt{f(x)}= \sqrt{\lim f(x)}$.

Answer (score 2):

There is a general theorem for the algebra of limits that

$$\lim_{x\to c}(F(x)G(x))=\left(\lim_{x\to c}F(x)\right)\left(\lim_{x\to c}G(x)\right)$$

if both limits on the right hand side exist. Letting $F(x)=G(x)=\sqrt{f(x)}$, we get

$$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\left(\lim_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}\right)^2$$

In particular, the limit exists.

Answer (score 0):

According to the more general definition of limit that is

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow c} f(x) = L \iff \forall \varepsilon >0\, \exists \delta > 0: \forall x\in D\quad 0<\vert x-c\vert <\delta \implies \vert f(x)-L\vert <\varepsilon $$

we have that for $f(x)=\operatorname{sign} (x-c)$

$$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)} =1 \quad \lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=N.E.$$

What is always true independently from the definition is that

$$\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)} =L \implies  \lim\limits_{x\to c}\left|f(x)\right|=L^2$$

Refer also to the related

- [What is $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\frac 1x)}{\sin (\frac 1 x)}$ ? Does it exist?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2889055/505767)

Comment: Thank you, what do you mean by "sign"? Can you define what you mean?

Comment: @DaltonKozak Refer to that [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).

Comment: This answer makes no sense.

Comment: @Kosh What is the point which is no sense?

Comment: @user, the function $\sqrt{\text{sign}(x-c)}$ is not defined for $x\lt c$.

Comment: Actually $\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}$ is $\lim\limits_{x\to c^+}\sqrt{f(x)}$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to c^+}f(x)$ does exist !

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes indeed but according to the given definition of limit th elimit exists, it is the same for $\lim x \to 0 \log x$, we exclude form the domain the points where the function is not defined.

Comment: But we write $\lim\limits_{x\to 0^+}\log x$ not $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\log x$ indeed the function is defined for $x>0$.

Comment: @Angelo It depends upon the definition we are referring to. It is always a point of discussion here :) Take also a look to the given link.

Comment: @user, ah, I think I see now what you're getting at: the "$\forall x\in D$" is crucial.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes indeed, it seems this is the "more general" definition of limit that is the definition which allows to define limits also for problematic cases. In the given link this point is discussed in great detail with some different point of view!

Comment: If $f(x)\ge0$ for all $x\in(a,b)$ and $a<c<b$, there are not counterexamples.

Comment: @Angelo Yes of course, with these assumption it works well! My point is that when we state a general property or a theorem for limits we should always indicate the definition we are referring to.

Comment: But I think that even though the OP did not write it explicitly, the function $f(x)$ is non-negative for $x>c$ and for $x<c$, otherwise he would write $\lim\limits_{x\to c^+}\sqrt{f(x)}$. For that reason, I said your answer makes no sense. Of course your answer is formally correct according to the definition of limit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\;a,\;b,\;c\in\mathbb{R}\;$ such that $\;a<c<b\;.$

Let $\;f(x):(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}\;$ be a function such that

$f(x)\ge0\;$ for all $\;x\in(a,b)\;.$

---

If there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;$ then

$\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to c}\left[\sqrt{f(x)}\cdot\sqrt{f(x)}\;\right]=\\\qquad\quad=\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}\cdot\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}=l^2\;.$

---

Conversely, if there exists $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c}f(x)=l\in\mathbb{R}\;,\;$ then $\;l\ge0.$

If $\;l=0\;,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}=0\;,\;$ indeed

$0\le f(x)<\epsilon^2\implies 0\le\sqrt{f(x)}<\epsilon\;.$

If $\;l>0\;,\;$ then $\;\lim\limits_{x\to c}\sqrt{f(x)}=\sqrt{l}\;,\;$ indeed

$0\le l-\epsilon^2<f(x)<l+\epsilon^2\implies\\\implies\sqrt{l}-\epsilon\le\sqrt{l-\epsilon^2}<\sqrt{f(x)}<\sqrt{l+\epsilon^2}\le\sqrt{l}+\epsilon\;.$